# Infinite loop Error in merge sort

Tags: python, linked-list

I tried to write a function for generating a merge sorted list  from two singly linked lists:

```
def merge_lists(head1, head2):
    if not head1 or not head2:
       return head1 or head2 or []
       head = None
    while head1 is not None and head2 is not None:
          if head is not None and head1 is not None:
             head.next = head1
          else:
              if head is not None and head2 is not None:
                 head.next = head2
          else:
              if head1.value <= head2.value:
                 if not head:
                     head = head1.value
                     head1 = head1.next
                 else:
                    head.next = head1.value
                    head1 = head1.next
              else:
                 if head1.value > head2.value:
                    if not head:
                       head = head2.value
                       head2 = head2.next
                    else:
                       head.next = head2.value
                       head2 = head2.next
    return head
```

head1 and head2 are two linked lists generated by the function:

```
def to_linked_list(plist):
    head = None
    prev = None
for element in plist:
    node = Node(element)
    if not head:
        head = node
    else:
        prev.next = node
    prev = node
return head
```

The head which returns the merged list from the function merge_lists() can be converted into a list by using the routine:

```
def to_linked_list(plist):
head = None
prev = None
for element in plist:
    node = Node(element)
    if not head:
        head = node
    else:
        prev.next = node
    prev = node
return head
```

when  I give two lists input as plist1 = [1,2,3] and plist2 = [1,2,3] and convert them to linked lists head1 and head2 and call the merge_lists(0  function it was resulting in an infinite loop.can anyone please help me.

Comment: Can you go back and reformat your code - the indentation showing at the moment makes no sense

Comment: You never changed `head1` and `head2`, how could you break from the `while` loop?

Comment: How can I change the head1 and head2 values I am already moving the pointer in the list which has low value element.@WKPlus